# Parse JSON array from file using big-json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm

I have a big json file (>600MB) that contains an array of objects. It looks like this

```
[{"i":0,"name":"Steven"},{"i":1,"name":"Adrien"}, ....]
```

I'd like to parse it json object and because it's a big file I'd like to use `big-json` library. I have a code like this

```
import json from 'big-json'

const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./myJson.json')
const parseStream = json.createParseStream();
parseStream.on('data', function (myData) {
    console.log(myData)
})
readStream.pipe(parseStream)
```

the output looks like this

```
{ '0': { i: 0, name: 'Steven' }, '1': { i: 1, name: 'Adrien' }, ... }
```

How to parse it as an array of objects exactly the same way as it's in the file. ?

Comment: See https://github.com/DonutEspresso/big-json/issues/19. In the meantime, you can always just use `Object.values()` to get it back to an array

Comment: As of now, `big-json` doesn't have support for arrays. So it converts them into objects. You either have to use some other package or iterate over the resulting object & convert into array manually. A simple solution would be using `Object.values(myData);`